# Is their a guaranteed lifetime for file-scope variables declared in .c and .cpp files (JNI)?

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When calling JNI functions from Java in an Android app using JNI, is their a guaranteed lifetime for variables declared at file-scope? We call this function a few times, can the Android system unload our program from memory without terminating the app's process in order to conserve memory in between calls? Is our variable lifetime guaranteed for the life of the process?

```
#include <stuff>

int counter = 0;

extern "C" void com_package_Class_dostuffFromJava(JNIenv.....)
{
    LOG("Counter: %d" , counter);
    ++counter;
}
```

Comment: Yes. No. Yes. Bonus text.

Comment: (You may need to worry about thread safety though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operating system can swap or page memory, but I don't see why it concerns you. The 'guaranteed life' of a file-scoped variable in C is the life of the process.

Comment: Are you sure this is true for the Android platform where the system can just randomly destroy one of your Activity's, for example, without terminating the process? "If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop it from memory either by asking it to finish (calling its finish() method)", or simply killing its process.

Comment: Killing the process will reset the variable; calling a finish method won't.

Comment: There's System.loadLibrary(), but I don't see an unloadLibrary(), at least.

Comment: @svenoaks Killing the process *is* terminating the process, and that doesn't 'reset' but rather *destroys* the variable. Your point about loadLibrary() remains obscure.

Comment: My point is how do I know the System doesn't have a way of unloading the library, while the process remains active - my original question. The system has a way of dropping other application components from memory (as mentioned in my quote about Activity's), so it is not that much of a stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Your point is answered by my answer. The life of the variable is the life of the process. You state yourself there is no unloadLibrary().